# Python: Something like `map` that works on threads

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, map-function

I was sure there was something like this in the standard library, but it seems I was wrong.

I have a bunch of urls that I want to `urlopen` in parallel. I want something like the builtin `map` function, except the work is done in parallel by a bunch of threads.

Is there a good module that does this?

Comment: Do you mean you want map to start the threads (like pillmuncher's answer, map(urlopen, urls)), or will you manually start the urlopening threads, and want something like map to act on the results of each thread's execution, as they become available?

Comment: streams.fastmap() from Pyxtension: github.com/asuiu/pyxtension does exactly this - multithreaded map.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Someone recommended I use the `futures` package for this. I tried it and it seems to be working.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures

Here's an example:

```
"Download many URLs in parallel."

import functools
import urllib.request
import futures

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def load_url(url, timeout):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout).read()

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(50) as executor:
   future_list = executor.run_to_futures(
           [functools.partial(load_url, url, 30) for url in URLS])
```

Answer (score 58):

There is a `map` method in [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). That does multiple processes.

And if multiple processes aren't your dish, you can use [multiprocessing.dummy](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) which uses threads.

```
import urllib
import multiprocessing.dummy

p = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(5)
def f(post):
    return urllib.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%u' % post)

print p.map(f, range(3329361, 3329361 + 5))
```

Comment: This is great, but it won't work on python2.6 if run from a thread because of this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue14881

Comment: Works great in python 2.79 - currently the latest version of 2x, and quite well at it, too!

Comment: Awesome. Worth noting that underneath it's actually `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`

Answer (score 5):

Here is my implementation of threaded map:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

def thread_map(f, iterable, pool=None):
    """
    Just like [f(x) for x in iterable] but each f(x) in a separate thread.
    :param f: f
    :param iterable: iterable
    :param pool: thread pool, infinite by default
    :return: list if results
    """
    res = {}
    if pool is None:
        def target(arg, num):
            try:
                res[num] = f(arg)
            except:
                res[num] = sys.exc_info()

        threads = [Thread(target=target, args=[arg, i]) for i, arg in enumerate(iterable)]
    else:
        class WorkerThread(Thread):
            def run(self):
                while True:
                    try:
                        num, arg = queue.get(block=False)
                        try:
                            res[num] = f(arg)
                        except:
                            res[num] = sys.exc_info()
                    except Empty:
                        break

        queue = Queue()
        for i, arg in enumerate(iterable):
            queue.put((i, arg))

        threads = [WorkerThread() for _ in range(pool)]

    [t.start() for t in threads]
    [t.join() for t in threads]
    return [res[i] for i in range(len(res))]
```

Comment: You need to import `Empty` on the second line.

Answer (score 3):

The Python module `Queue` might help you. Use one thread that uses `Queue.put()` to push all urls into the queue and the worker threads simply `get()` the urls one by one.

[Python Docs: queue — A synchronized queue class](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I'd wrap it up in a function (untested):

```
import itertools
import threading
import urllib2
import Queue

def openurl(url, queue):
    def starter():
        try:
            result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except Ecxeption, exc:
            def raiser():
                raise exc
            queue.put((url, raiser))
        else:
            queue.put((url, lambda:result))
    threadind.Thread(target=starter).start()

myurls = ... # the list of urls
myqueue = Queue.Queue()

map(openurl, myurls, itertools.repeat(myqueue))

for each in myurls:
    url, getresult = queue.get()
    try:
        result = getresult()
    except Exception, exc:
        print 'exception raised:' + str(exc)
    else:
        # do stuff with result
```