# multiprocessing a large dataset through a complex class function with an iterator

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, pathos

I've searched probably 10 threads on multiprocessing looking but nothing seems to fit perfectly to my usecase. Here is a general idea of what I want to parallelize.

```
class foo():
    def boo():
        filename = 'path to the data file'
        with reader(filename) as fileReader:
            for id, feature in fileReader:
                 boo2(id, feature)
    def boo2(id, feature):
        *process feature then save the output to a folder*
```

Here I want to parallelize the call to `boo2()` where `fileReader` is an iterator (a [sequentialMatrixReader](https://pykaldi.github.io/api/kaldi.util.html?highlight=sequentialmatrixreader#kaldi.util.table.SequentialMatrixReader) from pykaldi) with tens of thousands of rows of `id` and `feature` where id is a string and each `feature` is a matrix (hundreds of row x tens of columns). `boo2` will compute a smaller matrix and save the result to a folder based on `id`. Each call to `boo2` are independent from one another so I want to parallelize it.

From my understanding I can't use `multiprocessing.Pool` since boo2 is a class function and I can't pull that out of the class due to it's complexity.

I don't know how to use `multiprocessing.Process` since the number of cores is much less than the number of rows of the iterator and I am unsure how to queue new calls to `boo2` once I've `start()` and `join()` processes (I've tried to split the fileReader into n batches and set a Process per batch however I'd much prefer to queue the calls in one-line vs multiple batchs)

I've also looked into `pathos` module since it doesn't have problems with class functions. However from sample use-cases the closest fit to my need is:

```
pathos.threading.ThreadPoolpool.imap(boo2, [feature for feature in fileReader])
```

But because of how large fileReader is I am unable to fit `[feature for feature in fileReader]` in memory.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the `multiprocessing` because of the class members, you need a separate function for that -- you're right about that.

Regarding using threads, I'd suggest you not using a simple comprehension `[feature for feature in fileReader]`, but read the features from `fileReader` in batches according to the CPU threads you have available, then run threads, wait for the completion and then read the next batch, etc.

Something like:

```
def make_next_batch( fileReader ) :
    batch = []
    for feature in fileReader :
        if len(batch) == BATCH_SIZE :
            yield batch
            batch = []
        batch.append( feature )
    if len(batch) :
        yield batch
```

Then you have to keep only `BATCH_SIZE` features in memory at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @lenik. However with this implementation I am bottlenecked by the slowest process during each batch. I was hoping to have each core process asynchronously if possible.

Comment: then you have to do what `threading.map()` does, but manually, without loading all the data into the memory. it's not that complicated, you have the bunch of threads, check if some of them are finished and spin the new ones with the next `feature` that comes from the generator. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329361/python-something-like-map-that-works-on-threads