# Python splitting big lists into smaller lists for check performance?

Tags: python, performance, list

What is the best way to split a large list (over 1000 items) for performance purposes? And use "parts" of a large list?

For example; I have a list of 10k addresses I want to scan. How can I split this list into a 4th, and finish the list by sections to increase performance?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) question similar to what you want?

Comment: Yes thanks that about does it

Comment: What are you doing with the list? Why do you expect splitting the list to help with performance?

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading all elements of the list, splitting will actually decrease your performance. You should profile your program (maybe post it in a question here, if you can sufficiently simplify it).

If you're not reading all elements, why are you using a list in the first place? Use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) or [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Operations on both are extremely fast.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) question for how to split an arbitrary list into smaller chunks. It doesn't explicitly cover increasing performance, so you might want to consider looking into the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module for actually manipulating those small lists simultaneously if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do an operation on the whole list, but it's slow doing it sequentially? I think you want a worker pool. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562757/is-there-a-multithreaded-map-function/2562799#2562799) help?