# Python Futures "When All"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am used to C# Task.WhenAll function. I would like to know if there is an equivalent for python's concurrent.futures.Future

I am looking for something like this:

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
future1 = pool.submit(lambda : 1 + 1)
future2 = pool.submit(lambda : 1 + 2)

aggregated_future = when_all([future1, future2])
print aggregated_future.result() # print result as a list [2, 3]
```

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562757/is-there-a-multithreaded-map-function

Comment: but be careful: threads may not be what you're looking for, since GIL makes them execute one at a time (no concurrency)

Comment: I am reading the post you shared. Thanks for the heads up - I plan to use the threadpool to do I/O work

Comment: asyncio.wait and asyncio.gather can do this for asyncio futures.  I don't have enough experience with concurrent.futures to know how to do it there, but obviously you could write something fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks @SamHartman, unfortunately I am using Python 2 and asyncio is not available. I could have written my own, but I am not sure how to do it correctly. E.g., I cannot decide which thread the when_all's future should run on. I feel when_all should be a think wrapper, instead of creating its own thread merely waiting the other two to complete.