# Updating batch image array in-place when using joblib

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

This is a follow-up question for my solution to the question below:

> [How to apply a function in parallel to multiple images in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374491/2956066)

[My suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373944/how-to-apply-a-function-in-parallel-to-multiple-images-in-a-numpy-array/48374491#48374491) works fine if the function `process_image()` has to return the result and then we can cache that to some list for later processing.

Since I want to do this type of preprocessing for more than 100K images (with array shape `(100000, 32, 32, 3)`), I want my solution to be very efficient. But, my list based approach will hog up lot of memory and thus it will also be inefficient (for further processing). So, I want the array to be updated **in-place** inside the `process_image()` function, when this function is called several times using [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/).

But, I'm having issues with updating the original batched image array **in-place**. I tried the [`suggestion by Eric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373944/how-to-apply-a-function-in-parallel-to-multiple-images-in-a-numpy-array/48374491#comment83738800_48374491) but it fails to update the original array **in-place**. I verified whether the array memory is indeed shared among the worker processes by printing the *flags* of the array inside the `process_image` function. Here is my code for doing so:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import exposure
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# number of processes
nprocs = 10

# batched image array
img_arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 32, 32, 3)).astype(np.float32)

# for verification
img_arr_copy = img_arr.copy()

# function to be applied on all images (in parallel)
# note: this function fails to update the original array in-place
# but, I want in-place updation of original array with the result of `equalize_hist`
def process_image(img, idx):
     """
     update original array in-place since all worker processes share
     original memory! i.e. they don't make copy while processing it.
     """
     print("\n processing image: ", idx)
     img[...] = exposure.equalize_hist(img)
     print("array metadata: \n", img.flags)
     print("======================= \n")

# run `process_image()` in parallel
Parallel(n_jobs=nprocs)(delayed(process_image)(img_arr[idx], idx) for idx in range(img_arr.shape[0]))
```

---

I even tried initializing an empty array using `np.empty()` of same shape as original batched image array and tried updating it but that also failed. I don't know where is it going wrong.

For checking whether the updation happened to the array or not, I used:

```
np.all(result_arr == img_arr)
```

where `result_arr` was initialized as:

`result_arr = np.empty(img_arr.shape, dtype=np.float32)`

Where am I going wrong and what's the bug in my code? All suggestions are highly appreciated!!

---

Print stats from above code to check whether memory is shared or not:

```
processing image:  914 
 array metadata:  
 C_CONTIGUOUS : True 
 F_CONTIGUOUS : False 
 OWNDATA : False     #<=========== so memory is shared
 WRITEABLE : True 
 ALIGNED : True 
 UPDATEIFCOPY : False 
======================= 

 processing image:  614
 array metadata: 
 C_CONTIGUOUS : True
 F_CONTIGUOUS : False
 OWNDATA : False     #<=========== so memory is shared
 WRITEABLE : True
 ALIGNED : True
 UPDATEIFCOPY : False
=======================
```

---

Comment: _"I verified whether the array memory is indeed shared among the worker processes by printing the flags of the array"_ - can you show us what was printed?

Comment: I think [this answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819779/102441)

Comment: @Eric I added the print stats at the bottom. This can also be obtained just by running above code :) Thanks for the reference! I tried setting the backend to `threading` but even that didn't work :( still the original `img_arr` remains unchanged.

Comment: `OWNDATA` means "this is a view of something", not that it's a view of the same thing

Comment: @Eric so doesn't `OWNDATA : False` mean `img` in `process_image()`  function is a view of `img_arr[idx]` which is the original image array?

Comment: Usually it would mean that `img` is a view of `img_arr` - remember, `img is img_arr[idx]`, so it's not even a view.

What I think is happening here is that `img` is a view of a process-local copy of `img_arr`

Comment: @Eric Not sure about how to check whether it's a process level local copy ... I would also suppose the same. As suggested in the other accepted answer, even setting `backend="threading"` is not updating the array *in-place*