# how can i call a def to be executed simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to call a function that takes a long time to execute(variable, from 0 to 300 sec.), it has to be executed as many times as there are lists in a json. How can I do it so that it executes three in parallel, for example?

To make it simpler the code in the explanation would be to call a function, this...

```
def f(x, j):
    print(str(x*x)+" "+" "+str(j))
    time.sleep(2)

j = 0
for i in range(10):
    j += 1
    f(i,j)
```

```
result

thread 1 : 0, 1
thread 2 : 1, 2
thread 3 : 4, 3
thread 1 : 9, 4

thread 2 : 16, 5
thread 3 : 25, 6
thread 1 : 36, 7
thread 2:  49, 8
thread 3:  64, 9
thread 1:  81, 10
```

Thread three could end before thread one, but I always want three runs.

Comment: check semaphore: https://superfastpython.com/thread-semaphore/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562757/is-there-a-multithreaded-map-function

Comment: Take a look at `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which are API's that allow the execution of concurrent tasks:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def f(x, j):
  print(str(x*x)+" "+" "+str(j))
  time.sleep(2)


j = 0
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as e:
  for i in range(10):
    e.submit(f, i, j)
```

You can also use the `.map()` method in this case. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) for more information.